# I'm looking for sample of different formats of video files for testing a player

Tags: video

I was wondering if anyone knew where I could find sample video if different type of formats. I need to test a player with several different files. Thanks in advances!

- Audio: .wma, .wav, .mp3, .pcm
- Video: .asf, .avi, .cpk, .dat, .dvix, .flc, .fli, .flv, .mkv, .mov, .mp4, .qt, .ram, .rm, .rmvb, .wmv, .3gp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try downloading **[FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/)**. This is a free tool to convert between almost all popular media formats.

For example if on Windows...

- Go to downloads and (under **Get Packages**) click Windows logo. Then click **Windows builds**.
- This will take you to **[Zeranoe](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)**. Make sure you choose 32/or/64 bit **static build** to download.
- In the downloaded ZIP, Just go into the "**ffmpeg**" folder and copy the **.bat** & **.txt** files and **folders** to a folder on your C: drive (mine is located at `C:\ffmpeg\`).
- Just run the bat file to start FFmpeg. This will bring up a Command Line window. Here you type your required ffmpeg **[commands](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html)**.

Conversion with FFmpeg is easy. Use `ffmpeg`(to run) + `-i` (for input) + `input filename` + `output filename`. The program (FFmpeg) is intelligent enough to analyse the in/output extensions and use correct codecs for those formats. After a few seconds it generates a new file in the current folder.

**Examples :**

To convert `mysong.mp3` into WMA format : `ffmpeg -i mysong.mp3 mysong.wma`

To convert `myvideo.avi` into MP4 format : `ffmpeg -i myvideo.avi myvideo.mp4`

You see how easy it is? There is a lot of support on the web, just Google "**ffmpeg how to XYZ**" where XYZ is your request & you'll see someone has asked it before and the solution is out there.

Answer (score 8):

You can find samples of various common and uncommon
multimedia formats here - http://samples.mplayerhq.hu